# Best way to maintain Google sheet permissions when creating a copy

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, copy, protected

each month  I create a copy of a google sheet file. It has quite a few sheets that have permissions - protected formula fields. The issue is, when copy is created only the owner can edit the protected fields, and if I want to add others it takes quite a while.
There are two possible solutions relying on File / Copy / Share with the same people, however if I want to add additional people it will take quite a while.

1. protect entire sheet, then I cold have only one permission per sheet, as it allows multiple ranges to be excluded. it is easy to add additional ranges and people. not sure if I may have some issues protecting entire sheet?
2. protect cells only, is there a way to group them or add more than one range to one permission?

Is there a better way to maintain and add people to many permissions?
Thanks

Comment: just to confirm, what you want is to copy the file and keep all the permissions for the protected ranges, as the copy is only shared to you. If that's the case, I'm afraid you need to do it programmatically in Apps Script. If you want to try that solution, check the answer below

Comment: thanks David, that looks great. I guess I could add people programmatically as well? I would be a bit reluctant to use a script, as unexpected results can occur. The other issue is I am looking for the simplest way to protect sheet as well. Rather than using 20 permissions per page, if I protect sheet it is easy enough to add editors and exclude two ranges (entry field and a checkbox). Is protecting sheet the best way to control permissions?

Comment: What's your specific use case? is it business related? A spreadsheet that shows performance rankings? What about creating a Data Studio dashboard, you'll be able to separate the data with the user interface

Comment: it is a simple google sheets where various users enter data in few columns, the protected cells calculate totals, group data and one column is for me to mark data that I have actioned. i am trying to learn how protected fields work and how best to improve the file itself. it is quite a mess atm.
Thanks David, may not be a bad idea to have a look into data studio

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a script that get an array of the protected ranges, and copy the same protected ranges to the new sheet.

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName('original');
  sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('copy'); 
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var p = protections[i];
    var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
    var p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
    p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
      p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
   }
  }
}
```

You can check more information on [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)